# HTML5 canvas: How to animate context?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

Is there any way how to animate context in the HTML5 canvas 2d?

I would like to create huge context but to show only small part of it on the screen. Then I would like to apply `translate` animation to scroll the context to show other parts of the context.

How should I do it?

Comment: animation is achieved by periodically redrawing the canvas. if you have a particular question about how to do it I would be happy to help.

Comment: So if I understand correctly then there is no way to do it. I need to do a basic animation where the whole "image" gets slowly shifted. The image will be mainly composed of rectangles (constructed on demand). The animation must be really smooth and very precise in timing. I was looking into CSS3, canvas2D and webgl but I have no idea which one to choose.

Comment: there is a way to do it, of course. how big is the whole image? you can create an off-line canvas that would hold the whole image, and another canvas that you would attach to the DOM which will show just the portion of the big canvas. then draw a portion of the large one into the small one using drawImage API.

Comment: Well the whole image could be even 50 screen images long or more. I hoped that when pre-drawing the whole image and then just shifting the image could produce smoother and less demanding animation. Am I right? BTW: Your idea definitely sounds interesting!

Comment: you can definitely use canvas translate instead of a second canvas, in any case the way to do it is to periodically redraw the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one canvas with a context that contains the entire thing you want to display, you can do this by making it onscreen if you need to so you can see what it looks like.

Then take what you have for making that and enclose it within a function or some kind of closure. Then use document.createElement('canvas'), and use it's context for the code you created for the display context.

You can then use .drawImage() when within the main context of your visible canvas, to draw the other context to the screen, and animate it upwards in your animation loop.

I wish I could've made that a little easier to understand, it's easier to understand by showing an example.

Off-screen rendering is essentially what I'm trying to explain.